# Jagged edges around the circle in OpenCV - Python

Tags: python, opencv

As the title says, I am trying to fix the jagged edges around the circle I created in OpenCV.

I've tried a few things i.e. `cv2.blur()`, `cv2.filter2D()`, they didn't do the trick.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import random

for i in range(5):
    img = np.zeros((512,512,3), np.uint8)
    H = random.choice(list(range(100,500)))
    V = random.choice(list(range(100,500)))
    S = random.choice(list(range(30,150)))

    cv2.circle(img,(H,V), S, (0,0,255), -1)

    img = cv2.resize(img,(750,750))
    f = (3-len(str(i)))*'0'+str(i)
    cv2.imwrite('circle%s.jpg' % f, img)

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

[image]

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I think you are looking to draw an antialiased outline. You can do that by setting the lineType parameter:

```
cv2.circle(img,(H,V), S, (0,0,255), -1, lineType=cv2.LINE_AA)
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks a lot. The circles look great now.

Comment: ..thickness=cv2.FILLED..    (magic constant -1 without argument name is bad coding practice)